# Apply ng-class to evaluate different expressions inside a P tag

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ng-class

I want to apply an ng-class to evaluate the negative values inside a < p > tag

```
   <p <strong>LW$:</strong> {{d.lw_metric}} <strong>LW:</strong> {{d.lw_metric_percentage}} <strong>L4W:</strong> {{d.l4w_metric}}</p>
```

I have my CSS:

```
.positive{ color: green}
.negative{ color: red}
```

But I don't know how tell angular to evaluate all the values inside the tag instead of doing one by one like this

```
ng-class = "{'positive':data.merchMetrics.LW_CHG_LY >=0,'negative':data.merchMetrics.LW_CHG_LY <0}"
```

Because I have five expressions inside this tag so I guess there's some way to avoid this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply shift that logic to controller

```
ng-class="evaluateClass(data.merchMetrics)"
```

Controller

```
$scope.evaluateClass = function(merchMetrics){
    var returnClass = "";
    //below for loop will iterate through each property of object
    //and will decide the class need to apply
    for (var key in merchMetrics) {
       if (merchMetrics.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          //you could also add the logic here
          //so that string will have positive & negative class once
          if(merchMetrics[key] > 0)
             returnClass = returnClass + "positive "
          else
             returnClass = returnClass + "negative "
       }
    }
    //you could return your class from here
    return returnClass;
};
```

Comment: @kennechu Glad to hear that it helped..Thanks :)